# Seifert surface with components

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I was wondering what the knot of a Seifert surface with 3 or more boundary components would be. Doesn’t  every Seifert surface have one boundary component by definition ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was thinking about examples of knots giving a rational Seifert surface to be the three punctured sphere and n punctured in general.

Comment: No, the definition of a Seifert surface is a connected oriented surface whose boundary is a particular knot or link. There's no condition on how many boundary components there are. (I'm not sure about a Seifert surface with zero boundary components -- this case might be worth excluding.)

Comment: @KyleMiller thank you for your reply, so if the boundary components are more than one then the seifert surface must have a link as a boundary. do we know any that give a 3 punctured sphere as a seifert surface?

Comment: Yes, there are infinitely many. One family is $P(2a,2b,2c)$ pretzel links.